# Convex Optimization: partial minimization preserves convexity

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am reading Boyd's Convex Optimization book.  In section 3.2.5 Minimization, he talks about why partial minimization preserves convexity. Specifically, 
If $f$ is convex in $(x,y)$, and $C$ is a convex nonempty set, then the function 
$$
g(x)= \inf_{y\in C}  f(x,y)
$$
(3.16) is convex in $x$, provided $g(x) > -\infty$ for all $x$.

Then the book explains the result in terms of epigraphs:
[I am not allowed to post picture yet, please see the book's explanation here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Okg.png)

That's all the book says in terms of epigraphs. My question is, doesn't this explanation ignore the infimum part in 3.16?  Why is $(x,y,t)\in epi f$ for some $y\in C$ automatically a convex set? Does it have any bearing on the fact that the infimum of $t=f(x,y)$ is obtained at "some" $y$?

I am not a math major and am learning convex optimization by myself, sorry if the question is completely obvious and naive.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

To answer my own question:
$(x, t)\in \text{epi }g \Rightarrow t\geq g(x)=\inf_{y\in C}  f(x,y)$, suppose the infimum is obtained at $y\star$, that means $t\geq f(x,y\star)\Rightarrow  (x,y\star,t)\in \text{epi}f$, therefore $(x,t)\in \{(x,t)~| \quad (x,y,t) \in \text{epi} (f),  \quad \text{for some} ~ y \in C  \}$.

However, there is a small problem in the above deduction regarding the equal sign condition, and that results in the counter point Ashkan provided. Fixing the problem should be easy (possibly the one Ashkan gave) so it will be omitted here.

Answer (score 2):

That's wrong I think !  The $\text{epi}(g)$ is not necessarly represented using that set in picture !

For example take $f(x,y) = x^2 + e^{-y}$ and $C =  [0 , + \infty)$. Then $$g(x)= \inf_{y\in C}  f(x,y) = x^2$$

And clearly $(0,0) \in \text{epi}(g)$ but $(0,0) \notin \{(x,t)~| \quad (x,y,t) \in \text{epi} (f),  \quad \text{for some} ~ y \in C  \}$

However, the result (lemma) itself is correct I think!

I guess that  we have $$\text{epi(g)} = \overline{\{(x,t)~| \quad (x,y,t) \in \text{epi} (f),  \quad \text{for some} ~ y \in C  \}}$$

Comment: The book has a short proof of the lemma. Still, why is $(x, y, t) \in$ epi$(f)$ for some $y\in C$ a convex set? I am trying to understand the epigraph interpretation of this lemma.

Comment: Can you put a link here connecting us the proof of lemma!  What I see in your link is definitely wrong!

regarding your second question $$\{(x,t)~| \quad (x,y,t) \in \text{epi} (f),  \quad \text{for some} ~ y \in C  \}$$ is convex, just take two points in it show that its convex combination is inset , not that $epi(f)$ and $C$ are convex sets. @MathJ

Comment: 1). $\{(x,t)~|(x,y,t)\in \text{epi}(f), \text{for ALL } y\in C \}$ is convex because $(x,y,t)\in \text{epi}(f), \text{for all } y\in C$ is convex and (x,t) is just its projection hence also convex. However, the argument in the book is "some" y, which means the set of y in (x,y,t) may not be C, it may be non-convex, I think it depends on the infimum condition in the original problem. 2). Your counterexample seems right, so the entire epigraph interpretation is not only confusing but also wrong? 3). The proof is in page 88. ie.bilkent.edu.tr/~mustafap/courses/bv_cvxbook.pdf

Comment: As I said in my pervious comment  the set $\{(x,t)~| \quad (x,y,t) \in \text{epi} (f),  \quad \text{for some} ~ y \in C  \}$ is indeed convex, but still it doesn't help to prove the lemma. 

Also the set $\{(x,t)~| \quad (x,y,t) \in \text{epi} (f),  \quad \text{for all} ~ y \in C  \}$  is out of scoop of this problem , and has nothing to do with $epi(g)$  

Again the main problem is that $$epi(g) \neq \{(x,t)~| \quad (x,y,t) \in \text{epi} (f),  \quad \text{for some} ~ y \in C  \}$$

Again The set in right side is convex (clearly) 
@MathJ

Comment: The set $T=\{(x,t)~| \quad (x,y,t) \in \text{epi} (f),  \quad \text{for some} ~ y \in C  \}$ , if you interpret "some" as "certain", then it is convex; however, the problem indicates "some" here means "a few": there is no reason to believe all infimum is achieved at the same $y$. So some $y$ is a subset of $C$. As a counterexample, consider $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, $C=[0,10]$, some $y\in C$ are exactly {1,2}. Then T becomes $T\star =\{(x,t)~| \quad t\geq x^2+1 \text{or } t\geq x^2+4 \}$, $(0,1)$ and $(0,4)$ are both $\in T\star$, but anything in between $\notin T\star$, i.e., $T\star$ is non-convex.

Comment: IN the world of mathematics, SOME means, there exists! @MathJ

Comment: You may not fix few elements in C! It says $(x,t)  \in T$ only if at least there exists a $y \in C$ such that $ (x,y,t) \in epi f$.  I don't know if you get it or not.

Comment: So "some" here means "a certain", then $T$ is indeed convex. Thanks for correcting my mistake. Like I said in my main post, the book's epigraph interpretation ignores the infimum part of the problem, if the original problem was  $g(x)= \sup_{y\in C}  f(x,y)$ or any method that choose a $y$ from $C$, the book's conclusion epi$(g)=T$ would still hold, but that can't be right. It seems to that the relation between epi$(g)$ and $T$ is quite far from equality. What do you think?

Comment: Is not that far  , if   $C$  is compact it is true, even in general it is not hard to prove that   $$\text{epi(g)} = \overline{\{(x,t)~| \quad (x,y,t) \in \text{epi} (f),  \quad \text{for some} ~ y \in C  \}}$$

Comment: Is that the complement of $T$? I don't think the complement of a convex set is convex. The goal here is to prove epi$(g)$ is convex.

Comment: That's the closure of T

Comment: I've understood the issue I was having and updated my original post. Thank you for your help!